# Game Center for iPad

Tags: ipad, game-center

```
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
if (leaderboardController != nil) {
  // start the leader board view controller
  leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
  leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
  leaderboardController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
  leaderboardController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
  leaderboardController.category = @"map1";
  RootViewController* rootVC = ((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication   sharedApplication].delegate).viewController;
  [rootVC presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
}
```

I have a iPhone app, it works fine with gamecenter.
But when I build a iPad version, the gamecenter leaderboard still display with iPhone Size( 320x480 ).

So I added this:`leaderboardController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;`
but the display is corrupted, the 3 buttons( today, this week, all time ) on tabbar are NOT fullscreen.
and a wood frame too.

Comment: It should not be a 320x 480 gamecenter.. It should be a somewhat squarish looking gamecenter.. =)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the ModelPresentation Form Sheet which opens not in a full screen:

```
troller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet
```